# Почему вкладка "Run" в IDEA как то необычно выглядит?

Tags: intellij-idea

Почему вкладка "Run" в IDEA как то необычно выглядит?

Обычно вроде бы перед строкой вывода того что в sout всегда 1 строка типа

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBr...

А тут ещё 4 раза Task почему то

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Да вроде вполне обычно, что вас смущает?

Comment: Ну обычно вроде бы перед строкой вывода того что в sout всегда 1 строка типа

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBr...

А тут ещё 4 раза Task

Comment: Просто gradle запускается, всё нормально

Comment: А что в Gradle всегда так?
А можно как то сделать чтобы 4 раза Task не выводидось?

Comment: А чем Task мешает?